# How can i add class on last div with javascript it length is change dynamic

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="block-region-side-pre"> 
     <div class="block">a</div>
     <div class="block">b</div>
     <div class="block">c</div>
     <div class="block">d</div>
</div>


 var allElems = document.querySelector("#block-region-side-pre").querySelectorAll(".block");

    for(var i=0; i< allElems.length; i++){
       allElems[i].className+=' lastblock'
    }
```

How can i find the last div lastblock to it. I am try to do it but it add on all div that classname is block

Comment: `document.querySelector("#block-region-side-pre").querySelector(".block:last-child");`

Comment: What about css :last-child?

Comment: :last-child is not working in moodle lms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ;)

```js
var allElems = document.querySelector("#block-region-side-pre").querySelectorAll(".block");

for(var i=0; i< allElems.length; i++);
allElems[(i-1)].className+=' lastblock';
```

```html
<div id="block-region-side-pre"> 
     <div class="block">a</div>
     <div class="block">b</div>
     <div class="block">c</div>
     <div class="block">d</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Use `last-child` selector and `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll` as you are targeting only one element.

```js
document.querySelector("#block-region-side-pre").querySelector(".block:last-child").className += ' lastblock';
```

```css
.lastblock {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="block-region-side-pre">
  <div class="block">a</div>
  <div class="block">b</div>
  <div class="block">c</div>
  <div class="block">d</div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** If elements are added dynamically and your script is being applied before elements are appended, Use css [**`:last-child`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) property,

> *The :last-child CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the last child element of its parent.*

```css
#block-region-side-pre div:last-child {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="block-region-side-pre">
  <div class="block">a</div>
  <div class="block">b</div>
  <div class="block">c</div>
  <div class="block">d</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
 var allElems = document.querySelector("#block-region-side-pre").querySelectorAll(".block");

    for(var i=0; i< allElems.length; i++){
       if (i == allElems.length - 1 ) allElems[i].className+=' lastblock';
    }
```

```html
<div id="block-region-side-pre"> 
     <div class="block">a</div>
     <div class="block">b</div>
     <div class="block">c</div>
     <div class="block">d</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No need to check for last element in every iteration simply after loop decrement loop counter and apply class;